# Massive display problem (css not loaded?) depending on used internet browser

Tags: layout, css

My pages (www.worg.ch and www.luxury-silk.ch) look good under IE and Google Chrome, but www.worg.ch is not displayed correctly in Firefox. Perhaps the CSS files are not loaded? luxury-silk Looks good on Firefox.
Any idea how to solve the Problem?

**IE**
[image: opened with Internet explorer]

**Firefox**
[image: opened with Firefox]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firefox probably didn't render your page correctly because of a Safe Browsing alert. Checking your site, I recognized a JS exception caused by a missing glider.js file. Trying to inspect that file led to a Safe Browsing warning from Firefox. Its content looked absolutely unsuspicious, though, seems like a false positive. However, the alert or the exception may have stopped your styles from loading, parsing, being applied, rendering, whatsoever. Once overriding the Safe Browsing alert manually, everything went back to normal.

You may have to check with Google and/or Mozilla what to do about the false positive Safe Browsing alert. There are forms online to report this to Google and perform further diagnostics.